# Neo4j, querying multiple lucene indexes while returning a pageable result

Tags: neo4j, lucene, cypher

I've been trying to write a cypher query which enables me to get results from multiple lucene indexes, while enabling a pageable result.

This is as far as I got:

```
START u=node:Index1(lucene_expression1) 
RETURN COLLECT(u) as clt 
START u=node:Index2(lucene_expression2) 
RETURN clt + COLLECT(u) as clt
UNWIND clt AS u 
WITH DISTINCT u 
RETURN u ORDER BY u.name SKIP 0 LIMIT 10
```

The problem is when the second index doesn't return any results,
no results are returned, ignoring the results returned by the first index.

I think this is because of the order of execution, that unless COLLECT or COUNT are the only returned fields, empty result set always returns empty result set.

Just to clarify, I know I can use UNION in order to get the full data set, but then I'll need to apply the paging outside of Neo4j, which I wish to avoid.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Works for me:

```
START n=node:node_auto_index(name="Neo2")
WITH collect(n) AS c
START n=node:node_auto_index("name:Neo")
WITH c + collect(n) AS c2 UNWIND c2 AS n
RETURN n
SKIP 0 LIMIT 10
```

see: http://console.neo4j.org/r/wrokab

Comment: Try it when the second query doesn't return any results http://console.neo4j.org/r/31fr9c